# How do I access an element in a dictionary key with multiple elements?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I stored several elements, namely, an array of String at a particular key in a dictionary that I created. However, I could not find anything, including the apple developer's guide, regarding accessing a particular element in a dictionary's key. Looking at the code below might make more sense.

```
import UIKit

var dict = Dictionary<Int, Array<String>>()
dict[1] = ["dog", "cat", "fish"]
dict[1]! += ["poop"]
dict[1]!.append("snacks")


print(dict[1])          //"[dog, cat, fish, poop, snack]\n"
```

So I want to access `dog` using a 2d like syntax, e.g., `dict[1][0]`. So I tried things like, `dict.keys[1].Array[0]`, `dict.keys.array[0]`, and `dict[1: [0]]` in order to access `dog`. However, none of these work. Anybody have a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary subscript in Swift returns optional, so you need to unwrap it:

```
print(dict[1]![0])
```

Comment: @JaeKim you're welcome ;) Please mark this answer as accepted to make it easier to find for others.